# Aligning an equation graph with an ybar graph

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, graphs

I am so desperately trying to align an equation graph (which consists of a bunch of sine waves) with a ybar graphs places on its right that represents its Fourier transformation. I have used the subfloat environment in order to have two distinct figures which I could then reference and caption individually. The problem that soon arose is that I can't seem to figure out how to align these two graphs properly, and I believe that the problem comes from the fact that the ybar graph has a different structure and layout than the normal graph. I have tried hiding the tick marks of the bar graph but that didn't fix the problem. How can I solve this? Thanks in advance!

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\subfloat[][]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,tick pos=left,width=9cm,height=8cm]
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, red, very thin]{6*sin(4*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, cyan, very thin]{4*sin(8*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, orange, very thin]{3*sin(12*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, green, very thin]{2*sin(16*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=200,blue, ultra thick]{6*sin(4*pi*deg(x))+4*sin(8*pi*deg(x))+3*sin(12*pi*deg(x))+2*sin(16*pi*deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}
        }
        \subfloat[][]{
        \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar,xmin=0,xmax=1000,tick pos=left, width=9cm,height=8cm]
            \addplot
                coordinates{(200,6) (400,4) (600,3) (800,2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    }
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Consider accepting the provided answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way, using the `floatrow` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{caption, subcaption, floatrow, tikz, pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\ffigbox{%
 \floatsetup{style=plain, heightadjust=object, valign=t}
\begin{subfloatrow} 
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{fig:1}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            ymajorgrids=true,
            grid style=dashed,tick pos=left,width=9cm,height=8cm]
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, red, very thin]{6*sin(4*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, cyan, very thin]{4*sin(8*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, orange, very thin]{3*sin(12*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1, samples=200, green, very thin]{2*sin(16*pi*deg(x))};
            \addplot[domain=0:1,samples=200,blue, ultra thick]{6*sin(4*pi*deg(x))+4*sin(8*pi*deg(x))+3*sin(12*pi*deg(x))+2*sin(16*pi*deg(x))};
        \end{axis}
        \end{tikzpicture}}
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\caption{}\label{fig:2}}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[ybar,xmin=0,xmax=1000,tick pos=left, width=9cm,height=8cm]
            \addplot
                coordinates{(200,6) (400,4) (600,3) (800,2)};
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{subfloatrow}}
{\caption{Sine waves and their Fourier transforms}\label{fig}}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1: Never heard of the `floatrow` package! I would have tried something with `scale only axis` as a first guess.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner:  It cooperates with `caption`, but has a drawback: one cannot load the `float` package (however, I believe it has similar functionalities).